# Unknow encryption type?

Tags: android, encryption, apk, smali

So Im trying to view this modded apk's smali files, and as of the new update they encrypted the strings. I don't think its base64 because it doesn't translate correctly. All the folders, and important string names are changed to unicode characters. Heres an example from a smali file:

```
.class final Lkik/㯊䅞㐭䴉㻷䴧䛨䣬㩍䏂㥻䑉䁈/㑏䱧㛫䚸㨲㧨㓩㲭䣝䶛䐶㬭㲎㶌㝖䱠㓼䳖/䷰㾢䲪䁐㷜㒴㕖㦁䐛䈊㧁㸱䏠㞈;
.super Lcom/kik/㲏㰫䑰㟏䚐䎶䖡䒸㝧䊵䏝㭅/䨼䖹㪤䖟䪙䇎䉐䢻;
.source "SourceFile"
```

Does this look like a common encryption type? or do you think it's custom made? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you sure its not binary file?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Im sure, I tried decompiling with a fresh download and still the same.